# Failure of Riesz Theorem for L-infinity

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider $L^{\infty }([0,1]).$ This prelim exercise is as in the title and the hint is to use Hahn-Banach. I would appreciate feedback. Here is my attempt:

Suppose, toward a contradiction, that every $T\in \left ( L^{\infty }([0,1]) \right )^{*}$ is of the form $T(f))=\int_{0}^{1}f\cdot hdx$ for some $h\in L^{1}([0,1]).$

Observe that $C([0,1)]$ is a linear subspace of $L^{\infty }([0,1])$ so if we define for each $f\in C([0,1)]$ the functional $T:f\to f(0)$, we can extend it via Hahn-Banach to all of $L^{\infty }([0,1]).$

Then, there is $h\in L^{1}([0,1])$ such that $f(0)=\int_{0}^{1}f\cdot hdx.$ If $\int_{0}^{1}hdx=0$ we may take $f=1$ to arrive at a contradiction.

Otherwise $E=\left \{ h\neq 0 \right \}\subseteq [0,1]$ satisfies $\lambda (E)> 0.$ Now consider for each integer $n$, $E_n=[0+1/n,1] \cap E$. If $\lambda (E_n)=0$ for all $n$, then continuity of the measure implies that $\lambda(E)=\lim \lambda(E_n)\setminus \lambda(E\cap\left \{ 0 \right \})=0, $ so in fact some $E_n:=E'$ must satisfy $\lambda(E')>0.$

Furthermore, there is an open set $U$ disjoint from $\left \{ 0 \right \}$ and a compact set $K$ such that $K\subseteq E'\subseteq U$ and $\lambda (E'\setminus K)<\lambda (E')/2$ and $\lambda (U\setminus E')<\lambda (E')/2.$

To finish, choose a continuous function such that $f(K)=\left \{ 1 \right \}$ and $f(U^c)=\left \{ 0\right \}$  Then $f(0)=0$ but $\int_{0}^{1}f\cdot hdx\neq 0$ and again, we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Once you have $f(0)=\int_{0}^{1}fhdx$, let $f_n$ be $1$ at $0$, $0$ at $1/n$ and linear in between, and set $f_n=0$ in $[1/n,1]$. Then bounded convergence gives $1=\lim_n f_n(0)=\lim_n \int_{0}^{1}f_n hdx = 0$.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Nice. Thanks.